# JDO Querying After Deletion

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I am working on an application that uses `DataNucleus JDO` as its `ORM solution`.  I have a method that does the following:

```
Obj obj = persistenceManager.getObjectById(Object.class, id);
persistenceManager.deletePersistent(obj);

...

persistenceManager.flush()

...
String sql = ...;
Query query = persistenceManager.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", sql);
query.execute();
```

The above all runs in a single transaction.  I understand that `JDO` does not commit changes to the `datastore` until the end of the transaction, but I was under the impression that calling `flush()` would `flush` my deletion to the `datastore` so that it would no longer be returned by my `query. But, that's not what I'm seeing.

Is there something I'm missing?  Also, as a side question, will changes `flushed` to the `database` with `flush()` be `rolled back` if an exception occurs after the flush within the transaction?

Comment: when you say "google app engine", are you referring to Cloud SQL (aka MySQL) or GAE/Datastore? because the "google-app-engine" tag would be of little relevance when using MySQL ... it reverts to a simple JDO + MySQL + DataNucleus question

Comment: The other thing you're missing is actually looking at the LOG, which tells you what is executed in the datastore when and with which connection